# Basic side-by-side nested <div> positioning

Tags: css, html

[HTML](http://sas98.user.srcf.net/guestlist/index.php) and [CSS](http://sas98.user.srcf.net/guestlist/style.css).

This really shouldn't be as difficult as I'm making it out to be - I'm sure the solution is quite simple.

I am trying to accomplish two things:

1) To have `#left` and `#right` within `.container` to sit side by side with `#footer` staying where it is. Ideally, `#right` will become just a divider (no text in it) that touches `#topstrip` and `#bottomstrip` and there will be a third div on the right hand side.

2) To have a logo on level with `#navbar` but on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the left and right div in the container and then use a clearfix to make them equally high: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Because we all run into this kind of layout issues over and over a couple of very good css frameworks have been created to do this heavy lifting. Letting you focus on building the content and not the boiler plate stuff. I personally use yaml (http://www.yaml.de/) and have not looked back since. I can recommend it whole heartedly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tables

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><div id="navbar"><img src="YOUR LOGO SOURCE HERE" align="left"/>navbar section</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="left">left section</div></td>
<td><div class="container">container</div></td>
<td><div id="right">right section</div></td>
</tr>
<td colspan="3"><div id="footer">footer section</div></td>
</table>
```

And then you can change the width and height of every `<TD>` as you want
The table is set to be on the whole page width, you can add `height="100%"` to table tag or you can add a custom width and height.
The `border="0"` you can change it to `border="1"` to view your table limits and so on.

Have fun :)